How To Set A GCloud Flag During Cloud Build Runtime?
I need to set a Gcloud deployment flag with an environment variable that I set during runtime. The reason for this is that I am trying to version my cloud run services and if the parameter TAG_NAME comes in as ver1.0.0 or ver1.0.1 I only ever want it to be the variable ver1.
So long story short I want to be able to use
_CUT_TAG=$(echo $TAG_NAME | cut -d '.' -f 1)

In the script below to set the parameter
 --tag $_CUT_TAG \

But every time I try to set it the function fails. Here is the entire command:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        _CUT_TAG=$(echo $TAG_NAME | cut -d '.' -f 1)

        gcloud beta run deploy my-service \
          --image gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/account-service \
          --region us-central1 \
          --tag $_CUT_TAG \

And here is the error I am receiving
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) argument --tag: expected one argument

which is telling me that the parameter isnt getting set.

I suspect your command's flags and values are being mangled.
When you use long flags (apart from being easier to understand), you can use = to bind to the value, i.e. --tag=value.
Try:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        _CUT_TAG=$(echo $TAG_NAME | cut -d '.' -f 1)

        gcloud beta run deploy my-service \
          --image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/account-service \
          --region=us-central1 \
          --tag=${_CUT_TAG} \
          ...

Because you're using bash, you benefit from the richness of the shell in your script. So you could, e.g.:
_CUT_TAG=$(echo $TAG_NAME | cut -d '.' -f 1)

printf "_CUT_TAG=%s" ${_CUT_TAG}

# Echo the gcloud command to see what's being generated
echo gcloud beta run deploy my-service \
--image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/account-service \
--region=us-central1 \
--tag=${_CUT_TAG} \
...

Please consider providing a minimal-repro of your issue in your questions. Your YAML snippet is less value to future readers and requires more work to recreate your issue by those responding.
